# Query inner value in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

all
I'm trying to do a join in MongoDB but also, I need to check for conditions and to do a sum on inner values of what comes back from the join.
I will explain.
Currently I have this simple join query which looks like this:

```
db.Sets.aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup:
                    {
                        from: "ExecutionTasks",
                        localField: "identifier",
                        foreignField: "setIdentifier",
                        as: "execTask"
                    }
                }
            ])
```

It returns the following results:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Demo Set",
    "identifier" : "demo-set",
    "description" : "Demo Set",
    "creator" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "admin"
    },
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-03-24T20:09:55.120Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-03-24T20:09:55.120Z"),
    "execTask" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "isActive" : 1,
            "type" : "count",
            "threshold" : {
                "default" : "0",
                "deviations" : []
            },
            "name" : "amishay",
            "setIdentifier" : "demo-set",
            "description" : "a",
            "query" : {
                "source" : 1,
                "text" : "select * from t"
            },
            "creator" : {
                "id" : 1,
                "name" : "admin"
            },
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-03-27T20:03:22.275Z"),
            "updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-03-27T20:03:22.275Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "isActive" : 0,
            "type" : "count",
            "threshold" : {
                "default" : "0",
                "deviations" : []
            },
            "name" : "amishay2",
            "setIdentifier" : "demo-set",
            "description" : "test",
            "query" : {
                "source" : 1,
                "text" : "select * from t"
            },
            "creator" : {
                "id" : 1,
                "name" : "admin"
            },
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-03-27T20:03:57.248Z"),
            "updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-03-27T20:03:57.248Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to do is to return only the length of the array (execTask) and also only those with the attribute isActive which equals to 1.
So basically I want to get something like:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "Demo Set",
        "identifier" : "demo-set",
        "description" : "Demo Set",
        "creator" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "admin"
        },
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-03-24T20:09:55.120Z"),
        "updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-03-24T20:09:55.120Z"),
        "execTask" : 1
}
```

I checked online numerous questions but I only saw examples which query the collection attribute and not the joined collection attribute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage after [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). The below stage will [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and calculate the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) for query criteria.

`$filter` operator is to used to filter the `execTask` array contents in-place on the mentioned criteria.

[Expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions) $ and $$ to reference the fields / aggregation operators / aggregation stages and inner variables respectively.

`$size` operator to calculate the length of filtered array.

`$addFields` overwrites the existing field `execTask` to replace its value with the calculated size.

```
{
    $addFields: {
        "execTask": {
            $size: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$execTask",
                    as: "result",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$result.isActive", 1]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! it works! :) why didn't you use the sum operator? and do you have a link which explains all of the aggregation options? I never saw the addFields option. also, the dollar symbol thing. when do I use it? It looks like it's the prefix of the operators but then I see you also used it when you wrote "$execTask" and also you used 2 dollar signs when you wrote "$$result.isActive"... I just don't know the rules for that dollar sign and when it should be used. if you have a link for and explanation it would be amazing. thanks again! :)

Comment: You are welcome. Added links and short explanation. I'm not sure why you brought up `$sum` operator.  The alternative option which will need you to `$unwind` the `execTask` array into embedded documents followed by `$match` to keep only `isActive` embedded  documents  and use `$group` with `$push` embedded documents back into `execTask` array and calculate the `$size`. Please feel free to ask more questions if you have.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I have another questions. let's say I want also to create a filter /sorting/ skipping some records, all of that logic should come after the  lookup and the addfields right? I mean I would want to use $match to match the output collection to query, I would like to add the option of $skip and $limit. thanks!

Comment: It really depends. Aggregation pipeline stages are processed sequentially. `$match` on input collection  should be first stage in aggregation pipeline. `$match` on joined collection can be added after `$lookup` stage. `$limit / $skip / $sort` should be applied before `$lookup`. Some stages are optimized so order may not matter.  More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/. You can create more questions if you need definite answers with proper example.

Comment: so $sort/$limit/$skip needs to be before the lookup? what happens if I want to sort by a field I only have access to after the join?

Comment: `$sort` can be after `$lookup`. You've to be careful when sorting on the joined collection field as you get a array of output collection. You have to `$unwind` the array before you can apply sorting on the field.

Comment: the field I'm sorting on is the field you help me here to get the count of so it's not an array. I think I will manage from here. much appreciation.

Comment: Hey, I'm using now the query. execTask will hold the count of execution tasks I have. I want to omit every record which has 0 count. where should I put this condition? I think I cannot put it in the $match because $addFields comes after that, so it won't recognize it.

Comment: you can  add a `$match` after `$addFields`. Something like `$match:{execTask:{$ne:0}}`